# How to build TypeScript with Bazel

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, npm, bazel

this is a question for the Bazel (Blaze) team: what's the recommended approach to include Bazel as a build system for modern web apps (written in Typescript)? Can you provide a basic setup (maybe a starter) showcasing this?

Cheers.

Comment: Did you look at rules_typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_typescript have a decent readme.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the link. May I ask a related question: what if I need to also build HTML and sass files, copy assets around? My point is that I want to use Bazel as my main build system for my front end apps. Is there any set of rules for that?

Comment: Check out the github repo, there's rules_sass, some stuff for webdriver testing etc. Plus if something is missing, it's not that hard to write custom rules.